# Angular8(kendo chip)- Cannot read properties using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

Following are the code used in Angular8 for kendo chip

```
<kendo-chip-list [selection]="'multiple'" (selectedChange)="onShowColumnChange($event)" class="pane-popup">
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
         <li *ngFor="let column of totalColumns | slice: (i*itemsPerPane); let j=index;">
               <kendo-chip *ngIf="j < ((i+1)*itemsPerPane) && j<itemsPerPane"  [label]="column"  
                         [selected]="shownColumns.includes(column)" class="pane-popup"> 
               </kendo-chip> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</kendo-chip-list>
```

When i call list property chip.label is giving undefined.(Below is the typescript code)

```
import { ChipComponent } from "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons";

onShowColumnChange(chips: ChipComponent[]){
  for(let chip of  chips){   
      console.info(chip.selected + " " + chip.label );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how does ChipComponent iinterface/type looks like?

Comment: added import statement

Comment: anybody please help

Comment: Does property called 'label exists in ChipComponent interface?